# Filtering ASP health monitoring events

Tags: asp.net, iis, health-monitoring

I've recently added ASP.NET health monitoring to my site. Right now its setup with just a single rule:

```
<add name="Email Event Monitor" 
     eventName="Application Lifetime Events" 
     provider="MailWebEventProvider" 
     profile="Default" minInstances="1" 
     maxLimit="Infinite" minInterval="00:01:00" custom="" />
```

The problem is my site uses a CMS and I am constantly getting spammed with "Application compilation is starting." events. How can I filter out these events?

Also, where is the list of possible values for the `eventName` attribute of the rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change the `eventName` from "Appliction Lifetime Events" to "All Errors", that way you will only get errors, rather than life-cycle events.

You can get the list of possible values for `eventName` on your system from your root web.config file (located in `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\framework_version\CONFIG`) in the `<eventMappings>` section of `<healthMonitoring>`.